# Integration problem in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and let $m$=inf{$f(x)|x\in [a,b]$}, $M$=sup{$f(x)|x\in[a,b]$}.

Prove that for any partition $P$ and sample set $S$, $m(b-a)\leq RS(f,P,S)\leq M(b-a)$.

My attempt: $RS(f,P,S)=f(s_1)\Delta x_1 + ... + f(s_n)\Delta x_n$ ; $m(\Delta x_1 + ... + \Delta x_n)\leq f(s_1)\Delta x_1 + ... + f(s_n)\Delta x_n$.

Then what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $$ m\leq f(x_i^{*}) \leq M,\quad x_i^*\in [x_{i-1}, x_i]\implies m\Delta x_i\leq f(x_i^*)\Delta x_i\leq M\Delta x_i. $$

Can you finish it now?

Comment: Yeah, I got it done before your hint. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Good for your. You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

ANOTHER HINT: $$\Delta x_1+\ldots+\Delta x_n=b-a$$